# Pegar endereço de array com ID e usar em um IF

Tags: javascript

Duvida básica preciso pegar o endereço do array que contem um id e utilizar em um if, OUTRA: é possivel fazer um array de id? o que quero fazer é ao clicar na imagem apareça a descrição do atributo do objeto orgaos, simplificando clicar na imagem e aparecer determinada descrição por um alert, não consegui editar o código desculpe ;-; meu código:

```
function teste(){  
        let selecao = [document.getElementById('cerebro'), 
                       document.getElementById('pulmao'), 
                       document.getElementById('coracao'),
                       document.getElementById('rim'),
                       document.getElementById('encefalo'),
                       document.getElementById('esofago'),
                       document.getElementById('estomago'),
                       document.getElementById('intestino'), 
                       document.getElementById('figado')]

        orgaos = { cerebro: 'parte do sistema nervoso central situada na caixa craniana dos vertebrados e que recebe estímulos dos órgãos sensoriais, interpretando-os e correlacionando-os com impressões armazenadas, a fim de acionar impulsos motores que, essencialmente, controlam todas as atividades vitais',
                   coracao: 'O coração é um órgão muscular presente nos humanos e em outros animais que bombeia o sangue através dos vasos sanguíneos do sistema circulatório',
                   encefalo: 'conjunto do tronco cerebral, cerebelo e cérebro, parte superior do sistema nervoso central que controla o organismo.' , 
                   esofago: 'onduto musculomembranoso que liga a faringe ao estômago',
                   pulmao: 'cada um de dois órgãos respiratórios promovem as trocas gasosas, fornecendo oxigênio a todo o corpo',
                   rim: 'Rim cada um dos dois órgãos são os principais órgãos do sistema excretor e osmoregulador dos vertebrados',
                   estomago: 'O estômago é um órgão presente no tubo digestivo, situado logo abaixo do diafragma, Nele, os alimentos são pré-digeridos e esterilizados, a fim de seguirem para o intestino, onde são absorvidos.',
                   intestino: 'O intestino é um órgão em forma de tubo que se estende desde o final do estômago até ao ânus, permitindo a passagem dos alimentos digeridos, facilitando a absorção dos nutrientes e a eliminação dos resíduos.',
                   figado: 'glândula volumosa anexa ao tubo digestivo que realiza sínteses e transformações complexas de diversas substâncias'}

        // Isso aqui que preciso fazer mais não funfa ;-;
         if (selecao == selecao[0]) {
            document.getElementById('cerebro').innerHTML = alert(orgaos.cerebro)
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que você não precisa de um array. Basta enviar o id como parâmetro na função e mostrar o valor da respectiva chave do objeto `orgaos`:

```js
function teste(id){

   let orgaos = { cerebro: 'parte do sistema nervoso central situada na caixa craniana dos vertebrados e que recebe estímulos dos órgãos sensoriais, interpretando-os e correlacionando-os com impressões armazenadas, a fim de acionar impulsos motores que, essencialmente, controlam todas as atividades vitais',
                   coracao: 'O coração é um órgão muscular presente nos humanos e em outros animais que bombeia o sangue através dos vasos sanguíneos do sistema circulatório',
                   encefalo: 'conjunto do tronco cerebral, cerebelo e cérebro, parte superior do sistema nervoso central que controla o organismo.' , 
                   esofago: 'onduto musculomembranoso que liga a faringe ao estômago',
                   pulmao: 'cada um de dois órgãos respiratórios promovem as trocas gasosas, fornecendo oxigênio a todo o corpo',
                   rim: 'Rim cada um dos dois órgãos são os principais órgãos do sistema excretor e osmoregulador dos vertebrados',
                   estomago: 'O estômago é um órgão presente no tubo digestivo, situado logo abaixo do diafragma, Nele, os alimentos são pré-digeridos e esterilizados, a fim de seguirem para o intestino, onde são absorvidos.',
                   intestino: 'O intestino é um órgão em forma de tubo que se estende desde o final do estômago até ao ânus, permitindo a passagem dos alimentos digeridos, facilitando a absorção dos nutrientes e a eliminação dos resíduos.',
                   figado: 'glândula volumosa anexa ao tubo digestivo que realiza sínteses e transformações complexas de diversas substâncias'}
   
   document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = orgaos[id];
}
```

```css
img{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <img onclick="teste('cerebro')" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/143275/isolated/preview/5868497c009323a44151a21a6abe7b51---rg--o-humano-do-c--rebro-by-vexels.png">
   <div id="cerebro"></div>
</div>
<div>
   <img onclick="teste('coracao')" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT5xaYgajRSwbofYW_JqKWZBjuz3DSj5KO0sGZt7Bq4gnSlqyvZ">
   <div id="coracao"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: funcionou direitinho mais sinceramente bugou mina lógica kkk como que não precisava indicar o lugar do atributo do objeto no ' document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = orgaos[id];' o id do html fez uma espécie de ligação com as chaves dos atributos do objeto?

Comment: Sim, mais ou menos isso. Veja que coisas se interligam.

Comment: Pensei até na idéia de referenciação de endereços na memória mais ainda não se encaixa kkk é algum recurso especial só pode, nunca ia pensar numa solução assim, brigadão deu tudo certo , mais é muito curioso.....